# How do I flag a question with two different questions in it?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/252517/1) posted by a new user who is having some issues with his new Ubuntu 12.10 installation. He asked two different questions in it, one about no wireless with his Broadcom 4313 (which is a common question on AU), and he can't boot into Ubuntu, only his Windows 7 installation.

How should I flag it?

If not flag, what should I do with it?

**Update:** I noticed that user Flimm [completely edited out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252517/broadcom-wireless-doesnt-work) one of the questions; is this the way that these types of questions should be dealt with?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I usually edit out the 2nd part and leave the first question, then I leave a comment similar to:

> Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, this site works best when there's one question per post, I've edited out your second question, feel free to repost it as a new question, thanks!

Usually I don't feel the need to flag multiple question posts.

Comment: Edit the additional questions out quickly before somebody tries to answer all the questions.